# Yii2 dropdown list selected value

Tags: yii2

I don’t understand how dropdown list works. I want to take selected value from dropdown list.

My code looks like:

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['options' => ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']]) ?>
     <?= $form->field($model1, 'test')->dropDownList($items)->label(false);?>

    <button>Submit</button>
    <?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

where `$items =[‘A’,‘B’,‘C’…‘Z’];`

And the default displayed value for this is ‘A’, i want to change this value.

I’ve tried with `$model1->test`, but this is not my selected value.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you need to make a prompt:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'test')->dropDownList($items
    , 'prompt' => ' -- Select Value --']) ?>
```

If another scenario
Lets say you chose to select 'B' from your array:

```
$items =[‘A’,‘B’,‘C’…‘Z’];
```

the key of 'B' is 1 so you need to do this:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'test')->dropDownList($items)
,['options' => [1 => ['Selected'=>'selected']]
, 'prompt' => ' -- Select Value --']) ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In `ActiveForm`, your model field value is **selected** as the value.

In Html, there is **another property** that you can set the **default value**

You can use the `activeDropDownList()` in HTML for the given model attribute.

**syntax in Yii2 ActiveForm :**

```
<?= Html::field($yourModel, 'name_field_db')->dropDownList(
        [items-array of data],
        [options]
    ); ?>
```

**syntax HTML:**

```
<?= Html::dropDownList($name, $selection = null, $items = [], $options = []) ?>
```

**data as array**:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'name')->dropDownList(['1' => 'on', '0' => 'off'],['prompt'=>'Select Option']); ?>
```

**display the database data in the dropdownList via `ArrayHelper::map`.**

```
    // get fields from database for make itemList
    $yourModels=model::find()->all(); // Query(by Active record or Query Builder or ..)

    $itemList=ArrayHelper::map($yourModels,'filed_id','filed-name');

    echo $form->field($newModel, 'filed-name')->dropDownList($itemList,['prompt'=>'Please select']);
```

Can for ActiveForm: `$model->field = $model->isNewRecord? 'value' : $model->field;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code you should change ModelName to your model class name, it will be work.

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'test')
      ->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(app\models\ModelName::find()->all(),'id','test'))
 ?>
```